# Problem keeping CSS footer on bottom

Tags: html, css, footer

Hey, I'm having trouble with a relative positioned footer.  I'm using a clearfooter div to keep the footer at the bottom of each of my pages.  This works fine for all resolutions except for 1440x900, any ideas why this resolution would make the header raise up 10 or so pixels off the bottom?

CODE: http://pastie.org/929802

Comment: some example code would be helpful.

Comment: Edit your question don't add it as a comment. Also we need some html too like the tags that make up your structure :)

Comment: The bottom of the content or the bottom of the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use a method similar to this:

http://fortysevenmedia.com/blog/archives/making_your_footer_stay_put_with_css/P25/

Which if that is the case you need a little bit more css to help your footer stay put. You would need to give your footer a height that is the same as your clearfooter class:

`#footer {height:150px; position:relative}`

And also add to your wrapper class:

`#wrapper {margin:-150px; position:relative; min-height:100%}`

Of course if your footer is not 150px tall then you need to adjust the classes (ie #wrapper's negative margin, #footer's and .clearfooter's height) to be the correct size.